# Performance degrade while fetching it from views PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance

I am running this query and i am getting a low performance. We have fetch the data from views but some how it is giving low performance.

I got explain analyze

````
  "Aggregate  (cost=387.95..387.96 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.561..0.561 rows=1 loops=1)"
    "  ->  Unique  (cost=387.95..387.95 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.558..0.558 rows=0 loops=1)"
    "        ->  Sort  (cost=387.95..387.95 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.558..0.558 rows=0 loops=1)"
    "              Sort Key: at.id, at.cid, at.created_at, ps.channel"
    "              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
    "              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=15.89..387.94 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.525..0.525 rows=0 loops=1)"
    "                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=15.78..269.20 rows=56 width=108) (actual time=0.212..0.347 rows=11 loops=1)"
    "                          Hash Cond: (at."LV" = br.id)"
    "                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.47..261.68 rows=56 width=105) (actual time=0.078..0.209 rows=11 loops=1)"
    "                                Join Filter: (at."aRR" = ar.id)"
    "                                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 11"
    "                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=8.47..260.00 rows=56 width=89) (actual time=0.071..0.196 rows=11 loops=1)"
    "                                      Hash Cond: (at."Type" = at.id)"
    "                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=6.28..257.60 rows=56 width=90) (actual time=0.043..0.161 rows=11 loops=1)"
    "                                            Join Filter: (at."Src" = sa.id)"
    "                                            Rows Removed by Join Filter: 231"
    "                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on at  (cost=6.28..252.88 rows=67 width=94) (actual time=0.026..0.109 rows=11 loops=1)"
    "                                                  Recheck Cond: (created_at > '2018-01-05 11:33:28'::timestamp without time zone)"
    "                                                  Filter: (status = 't'::text)"
    "                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=11"
    "                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on created_date_ids  (cost=0.00..6.28 rows=128 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=12 loops=1)"
    "                                                        Index Cond: (created_at > '2018-01-05 11:33:28'::timestamp without time zone)"
    "                                            ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..2.04 rows=10 width=28) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=22 loops=11)"
    "                                                  ->  Seq Scan on sa  (cost=0.00..2.03 rows=10 width=28) (actual time=0.002..0.006 rows=22 loops=1)"
    "                                      ->  Hash  (cost=2.09..2.09 rows=29 width=31) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=30 loops=1)"
    "                                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB"
    "                                            ->  Seq Scan on at  (cost=0.00..2.09 rows=29 width=31) (actual time=0.005..0.010 rows=30 loops=1)"
    "                                ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=3 width=48) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=2 loops=11)"
    "                                      ->  Seq Scan on ar  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=3 width=48) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=2 loops=1)"
    "                          ->  Hash  (cost=6.06..6.06 rows=355 width=35) (actual time=0.122..0.122 rows=370 loops=1)"
    "                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 33kB"
    "                                ->  Seq Scan on br  (cost=0.00..6.06 rows=355 width=35) (actual time=0.006..0.048 rows=370 loops=1)"
    "                    ->  Index Only Scan using prs_Src_application_at_activit_key on prs ps  (cost=0.11..2.12 rows=1 width=63) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=11)"
    "                          Index Cond: ((Src_application = (sa."Name")::text) AND (at = (at."Name")::text) AND (aRR = (ar."Name")::text) AND (LV = (br."Name")::text))"
    "                          Filter: (btrim((channel)::text) = 'V'::text)"
    "                          Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
    "                          Heap Fetches: 0"
    "Planning time: 7.735 ms"
    "Execution time: 0.721 ms"


    ```
````

Our views look like

```
 SELECT DISTINCT at.id,
        at.cid,
        at.created_at,
        at.status,
        ps.channel
       FROM at
         JOIN sa ON sa.id = at."Src"
         JOIN at ON at.id = at."Type"
         JOIN ar ON ar.id = at."aRR"
         JOIN br ON br.id = at."LV"
         JOIN prs ps ON ps.aRR::text = ar."Name"::text AND ps.at::text = at."Name"::text AND ps.LV::text = br."Name"::text AND ps.Src_application::text = sa."Name"::text
      WHERE at.status = 't'::text and
      trim(ps.channel)= 'V' and at.created_at > '2018-01-05 11:33:28'
```

This query is taking too much time. How to improve the performance of this query.

Comment: well, your explain analyze shows very low planning and execution time. Plus everything seems to be done in memory. How quickly you need to have it done? What version of PG is it?

Comment: Half a millisecond seems pretty reasonable. And it's only returning one row, so not sure where the performance issue is here.

Comment: Heroku PG version is 9.5 and it took almost 1 minute to fetch one row.